# Hotmail registration date

Tags: outlook.com

Does anyone know if there's a place where you can see the date you've registered your Hotmail or Live email address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [Windows Live account page](https://account.live.com/summarypage.aspx) should show a "Registered since" date. (This is for any Live/MSN account, not just for Hotmail.)